# How can I get the current reactions of a message and use it accordingly in Discord JS?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, javascript-objects

This question is a mix of discord js and javascript confusion. I am making a bot for a discord server and it needs to take the last message of the day (sent right before 12am) and react to it with a cookie. My current approach is to use `setInterval()` to check the time of day every couple of seconds and if it's exactly 12am, fetch the last message and react to it with a cookie. However, for some reason, the bot keeps reacting multiple times (because it can react with a random cookie emoji each time), which is not intended. My solution for that was to check the current reactions on the message and then react only if there are none, but somehow, I can't get that solution to work.

Code:

```
function cookieReaction(messages, cookies) {
    let cookieCount;
    let cookieMessage = messages.first();
    const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id === client.user.id

    // Check for "cookie" reactions (reactions from bot that are cookie emojis)
    cookieMessage.awaitReactions(filter, {time: 1000}).then(collected => {
        console.log(`${cookieMessage.content} has ${collected.size} cookies`);
        this.cookieCount = collected.size;
        console.log(`Cookie count inside is: ${this.cookieCount}`);
        }).catch(console.error);
    
    // If the message has no "cookie" reactions, then react with a random cookie emoji
    console.log(`Cookie count outside is: ${cookieCount}`);
    if(!this.cookieCount) cookieMessage.react(cookies[Math.floor(Math.random() * cookies.length)]).catch(console.error);
}
```

When I try getting the value of `cookieCount` outside the anonymous function (the function after `cookieMessage.awaitReactions()`), it keeps returning undefined. I've also tried with and without the `this` keyword, and tried moving the `cookieMessage.react()` statement inside the anonymous function but that just results in even more weird behaviour. In short, I just can't seem to get the value of `collected.size` as a condition for the if statement outside the anonymous function. Any approaches to solve this problem are welcome.

---

**EDIT - UPDATED CODE:**

```
async function cookieReaction(messages, cookies) {
    let cookieCount;
    let cookieMessage = messages.first();
    const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id === client.user.id

    // Check for "cookie" reactions (reactions from bot that are cookie emojis)
    await cookieMessage.awaitReactions(filter, {time: 1000}).then(collected => {
        console.log(`${cookieMessage.content} has ${collected.size} cookies`);
        cookieCount = collected.size;
        console.log(`Cookie count inside is: ${cookieCount}`);
        }).catch(console.error);
    
    // If the message has no "cookie" reactions, then react with a random cookie emoji
    console.log(`Cookie count outside is: ${cookieCount}`);
    if(cookieCount == 0) cookieMessage.react(cookies[Math.floor(Math.random() * cookies.length)]).catch(console.error);
}
```

The `cookieCount` now stores the correct value, but the bot is still reacting to a message even when the if statement says it shouldn't.

Comment: The `.then()` callback only triggers after `1000` ms, but everything outside doesn't wait for that. By the time you log, `this.cookieCount` hasn't been assigned. Put everything inside the `.then()` callback or use `async/await`

Comment: Furthermore, `this.cookieCount` is a totally separate from `cookieCount`. Use one or the other.

Comment: @Lioness100 Thank you, but when I did that, the if statement is no longer working. Like the ```cookieCount``` now stores the correct value, but the bot is still reacting to a message even when the if statement says it shouldn't. I edited my original post with the updated code.

Comment: So the bot reacts even when `cookieCount` is 0?

Comment: @Lioness100 The bot reacts even when ```cookieCount``` is not 0. I keep checking the logs and that's what it says. Sorry if this may be too much to help with.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's what I meant haha. Try changing `== 0` to `=== 0`. If that doesn't work, then idk.

Comment: What does `cookies` represent? An array of the cookie reactions?